# IPv4 to IPv6 wireless LAN router

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, ipv4

Does anyone know where I can find a home wireless router that does IPv4 to IPv6 address translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[apple airport](http://www.apple.com/airportextreme/specs.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Cisco 2621 :)

Works VERY well :)

Answer (score 0):

I know [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) supports both IPv4 and IPv6. I assume it will do protocol translation.